# Display the coordinates and time-stamp and other information by clicking the icon on Google Earth using simplekml in python

Tags: python, google-earth

I am trying to see the coordinates, time-stamps and some other information of a particular icon on Google earth by using simplekml in python. Here's the code I am using:

```
    style = simplekml.Style()
    style.labelstyle.color = simplekml.Color.red  
    style.labelstyle.scale = 0.05  
    style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png'
    for i in range(len(points)): # set of points as numpy array
       pnt = kml.newpoint(name='True Position:'.format([points[i][0], points[i][1]]))
       pnt.coords = [(points[i][0], points[i][1])] 
       pnt.style = style
    kml.save("test.kml")
```

I have a set of points whose geographical positions, time-stamps and for eg. altitudes are known for each point. When I run the above set of code I can only see the icons on Google earth. When I click any one of the icons, I see no information associated with the point, not even its position visible on Google earth.

How can I modify the above code so that by clicking the icon on Google Earth I see all the information (positions, time-stamps and altitudes)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a balloon (aka info window) pop up when you click on one of your points, and to have that balloon display certain attributes about that point.  There are several ways to do this in KML, and while I'm not very familiar with simplekml, it appears to be able to create the necessary KML structures.  There are a few ways to get the info you want into the balloons.  One would be to write out all the information (as text or HTML) into a "description" tag in each Placemark. Anything in the description tag will, by default, be shown when you click on a placemark.  If you just want a simple table of data to be shown in the balloon, then you can instead add the attributes into an ExtendedData section in each placemark's KML. Most KML renderers (including Google Earth) will show a basic table with your attribute names & values.  Finally, if you want more control over how the data from your ExtendedData is displayed, you can use a shared BalloonStyle that's applied to all the placemarks, and that BalloonStyle can contain an HTML template with variables representing your attribute names & values.  That way you can create a mini HTML page for your balloons, that gets filled in with the data for each placemark.

A good place to get more info on extended data and balloon templates is here:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

The simplekml documentation should show you how to create the necessary KML structures:
https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Finally, if you're willing/able to share a copy or sample of your KML file, we can suggest how to modify it to make sure the data you want is shown in the balloon.